# Remove sequential duplicate word separated by delimiter

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to remove sequential duplicate separated by delimiter '>' from journey column and also aggregate values under column uu and conv. I've tried

INPUT

```
a=[['journey', 'uu', 'convs'],
 ['Ct', '10', '2'],
 ['Ct>Ct', '100', '3'],
 ['Ct>Pt>Ct', '200', '10'],
 ['Ct>Pt>Ct>Ct', '40', '5'],
 ['Ct>Pt>Bu', '1000', '8']]
```

OUTPUT

```
a=[['journey', 'uu', 'convs'],
 ['Ct', '110', '5'],
 ['Ct>Pt>Ct', '240', '15'],
 ['Ct>Pt>Bu', '1000', '8']]
```

I tried below to split but it didn't work

```
 a='>'.join(set(a.split()))
```

Comment: You should do `a.split(">")` but this alone is not enough, sets are not ordered so you will end up with `Ct>Pt` instead of `Ct>Pt>Ct` what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your string by `>` and then you could use `groupby` to eliminate duplicate items in your string. For example:

```
x = ['Ct>Pt>Ct>Ct', '40', '5']
print(">".join([i for i, _ in groupby(x[0].split(">"))]))
# 'Ct>Pt>Ct'
```

You could use this as a lambda function in another groupby to aggregate the lists. Then sum each element of the same index by using `zip`. Check it out:

```
a=[['journey', 'uu', 'convs'],
 ['Ct', '10', '2'],
 ['Ct>Ct', '100', '3'],
 ['Ct>Pt>Ct', '200', '10'],
 ['Ct>Pt>Ct>Ct', '40', '5'],
 ['Ct>Pt>Bu', '1000', '8']]

from itertools import groupby

result = [a[0]]  # Add header
groups = groupby(
    a[1:],
    key=lambda x: ">".join([i for i, _ in groupby(x[0].split(">"))])
)
# groups:
# ['Ct, '[['Ct', '10', '2'], ['Ct>Ct', '100', '3']]]
# ['Ct>Pt>Ct', [['Ct>Pt>Ct', '200', '10'], ['Ct>Pt>Ct>Ct', '40', '5']]]
# ['Ct>Pt>Bu', [['Ct>Pt>Bu', '1000', '8']]]

for key, items in groups:
  row = [key]
  for i in zip(*items):
    if i[0].isdigit():
      row.append(str(sum(map(int, i))))
  result.append(row)
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[['journey', 'uu', 'convs'],
 ['Ct', '110', '5'],
 ['Ct>Pt>Ct', '240', '15'],
 ['Ct>Pt>Bu', '1000', '8']]
```

Comment: Thank you, Palvarez. This is amazing!! I was up until 3am last night and try to figure out and I found your answer right after I woke up this morning.  Thank you x100000

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to upvote and select my answer.